# How Can I filter array of numbers in Prisma?

Tags: mongodb, prisma, react-fullstack, server-action

I have a Product model with a prices field that is an array of numbers, and I want to filter products based on whether they contain price greater than or less than the given number In Prisma

This is The Product model:

```
model Product {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid()) @map("_id")
  title        String
  description  String
  price        Int[]
  extraOptions Json[]
  images       String[]
}
```

```
export const getProducts=async(page,name,price)=>{
    const pageNum = page; 

 const [products,count] = await prisma.$transaction([
        prisma.product.findMany( {
                take: 6,
                skip: pageNum * 6,
                where:{
                  OR:[  {title:{
                        contains:name,
                        mode:"insensitive"
                    }},
                   { description:{
                        contains:name,
                        mode:"insensitive"
                    }}]
                    ,
                   
 
           price:{has:{lte:Number(price)}}

      
                }
        }),
        prisma.product.count()

    ])

    revalidatePath('/store')
    return {products,count}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a raw database query

For example

```
export const getProducts = async (page, name, price) => {
  const pageNum = parseInt(page, 10); 
  const priceNumber = parseInt(price, 10);

  const query = {
    $or: [
      { title: { $regex: name, $options: 'i' } },
      { description: { $regex: name, $options: 'i' } }
    ],
    prices: { $elemMatch: { $lte: priceNumber } }
  };

  const [products, count] = await prisma.$transaction([
    prisma.$queryRaw`db.getCollection('Product').find(${query}).skip(${pageNum * 6}).limit(6).toArray()`,
    prisma.$queryRaw`db.getCollection('Product').countDocuments(${query})`
  ]);

  revalidatePath('/store');
  return { products, count };
};
```